# Validation of input text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have 'myTextarea' so users can put their text into it, and they should use only "numbers" and ",".

Text they input must be like this: 
    2,4,6,2,67,43,...number, comma, number, comma and so on.

This line of code helps me:

```
levelTextarea.restrict = "0-9,";
```

But the problem is that users can type many commas in a row
    2,,,,3,44,5,6,5,5....
and I need number,comma, number...

I will convert their input into an array.
Is it possible to validate input text, something like:

```
if (myTextarea is valid)
{
    continue
}
else
{
    trace ("invalid input");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but one simple way that comes to mind is just doing this:

```
var myValue:String = myTextarea.text;

while(myValue.indexOf(",,") >= 0){
    myValue = myValue.replace(",,",",");
}
```

Of course, if you just want an array of numbers at the end of the day, you could just do this instead:

```
//create the array
var arr:Array = myTextarea.text.split(",");

//loop backwards through the array and remove anything that is empty
for(var i:int=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(!arr[i] || arr[i] == ""){
        arr.splice(i,1);
        continue;
    }
    //convert the value to a number
    arr[i] = Number(arr[i]);
}
```

Now you'd have an array of all the number (separated by commas) from the text input

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
var a:String="4,4,4,4";

var valid:Boolean=true;


for(var i:int=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
{

        if(a.charAt(i)=="," && a.charAt(i)==a.charAt(i+1))
        {
            trace(a.charAt(i));
            valid=false;
        }

}
```

Only here I used strings.